# Invalid [] arguments when writing user declared function

Tags: r, arguments, sequence

A new R programmer here trying to play around with forex backtesting.
It seems to be a logistic error that I cannot find myself. I would greatly appreciate it if some more experienced R programmers can shed some light on me.

What I am trying to do with my code: I am writing a user declared function that takes 3 inputs: two vectors(columns) of type num (`pricehigh`&`pricelow`) and a constant `n` that is set to 10 as default. The code should return a vector `SwingHigh` of type char. 
I want the function to distinguish whether at point `pricehigh[i]` , the value is higher than all `pricehigh` at index `n` to the left and right. If true, `pricehigh[i]` should be labelled `"SwingHigh"`, otherwise, it should be labelled `"NotSig"`.

Here is code:

```
gann.swinghigh <- function(pricehigh, pricelow, n=10L){
 l <- length(pricehigh) #l == length of data.
 SwingHigh <- rep("",l) #create obj: empty char vector of length 'l'
 invalid_points <- c(1:n,l-n+1:l) #Create invalid points that needs to filled with NA.
 SwingHigh[invalid_points] <- NA #Assign NA to unvalid points. 
  for(i in n+1:l-n){ #for the valid points (point i), run:
   high_n <- rep(pricehigh[i],n) #for each valid point, create vector of length n. All with pricehigh[i]
   high_left <- rep(0,n) 
   high_right <- rep(0,n) #create empty num vector with size n.
   lookleft <- rep(NA,n)
   lookright <- rep(NA,n)

   high_left <- c(pricehigh[(i-n):(i-1)]) 
   high_right <- c(pricehigh[(i+1):(i+n)]) #fill vector with price high n points to the left/right of [i].
   lookleft <- high_n > high_left
   lookright <- high_n > high_right
    if(all(lookleft) & all(lookright)){
      SwingHigh[i] <- "SwingHigh"
    } else{
        SwingHigh[i] <- "NotSig"
   }
} 
  return (SwingHigh)
}
```

The code can be executed successfully but it is not doing what I want it to do.
When called `v <- gann.swinghigh(pricehigh=data$High, pricelow=data$Low)` the console shows a warning message: 
`Error in pricehigh[(i - n):(i - 1)] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts.`
`In addition: Warning message:In high_n > high_left :longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

My Question:
1. I understand what the first error means, it says I am trying to input a -ve value into the sequence. But in the loop, `i` starts from `n+1`, how will it ever be negative?
2. I precisely made both vectors of size `n` with the `rep()` function. How come it is not of the same length?

***The question has been solved. Error stemmed from the fact that I did not put '()' when using ':'

Comment: can you add some sample values for `pricehigh` and `pricelow` please? Your issue will be in these parts: `l-n+1:l` & `n+1:l-n`. If you are doing expressions around the `:` character, always wrap them in brackets e.g. try both of these in the console and see the difference: `1+2:3+4` & `(1+2):(3+4)`.

Comment: @Jonny Phelps Thank you so much that fixes the problem completely! 
Can you please explain why **1+2:3+4** returns '7 8' and **1+2:6+7**  returns '10 11 12 13 14' ?  What is going on in the background in R? Thanks again!

Comment: No worries :). Yeah sure, its actually doing the operation only on `2:3`. So what you end up with is `2:3 + 1 + 4`. It doesn't know that `1` & `2` are grouped together. The brackets do this. Same with the other e.g. it does the operation on `2:6` and then adds `7+1` to the output